# How to change the values of only part (slice) of a list of strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Does anyone know how to concatenate a list of strings using a for loop?

This works, without a loop:

## Extract Column Names

```
column_names = file.columns.tolist()
column_names[1]= column_names[1] + '_Vol_Adj'
column_names[1]
```

But does not work as part of the following loop:

```
for i in column_names[1:-2]:
    column_names[i]= column_names[i] + '_Vol_Adj'
    i = i+1
```

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-242-5509cede9f32> in <module>()
>       2 
>       3 for i in column_names[1:-2]:
> ----> 4     column_names[i]= column_names[i] + '_Vol_Adj'
>       5     i = i+1
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
> ```

Comment: `for i in column_names[1:-2]` does not iterate over the indices in the list. Try `print(i)` inside your loop and you'll see the issue. Related: [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you iterate over a the list `column_names` using `for i in column_names[1:-2]`, the value of `i` will be the element in the list (not the corresponding index).

In your case, one simple thing would be to use `enumerate`, as shown in the following example:

```
column_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
for i, val in enumerate(column_names[1:-2]):
    column_names[i+1] += '_Vol_Adj'
print(column_names)
#['a', 'b_Vol_Adj', 'c_Vol_Adj', 'd', 'e']
```

I am updating the value at index `i+1` inside the loop because we are starting the iteration at index 1.

Or you could use `range(1, len(column_names)-2)` as @Barmar [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487677/does-anyone-why-this-code-generates-an-error-when-concatenating-a-list-of-string/51487773?noredirect=1#comment89944568_51487773):

```
for i in range(1, len(column_names)-2):
    column_names[i+1] += '_Vol_Adj'
```

Comment: Another option is `range(1, len(column_names)-2)` then you don't need to use `i+1`

Answer (score 2):

Can also use `add_suffix` and `df.rename`

```
cols=['b', 'c']
ncols = df[cols].add_suffix('_suffix').columns

df.rename(columns={old:new for old,new in zip(cols,ncols)})
```

Answer (score 1):

See [@pault's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51487773/9209546) for how you can adapt your `for` loop with `enumerate` or `range`.

Given you are using Pandas, you may be interested in a NumPy-based solution:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCDE'))

arr = df.columns.values
arr[1:-1] += '_Vol_Adj'
df.columns = arr

print(df.columns)

Index(['A', 'B_Vol_Adj', 'C_Vol_Adj', 'D_Vol_Adj', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

It's important that you do not modify `df.columns.values` directly, as this has side-effects. Here we've modified a copy of the underlying NumPy array and then assigned back to the dataframe.