# How do I use dictionary to replace numbers in a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose we have a vector of 1’s of *size = 10*.
How can we write a code where the key is index and the value is replacing_number.
Eg.

```
Vector = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
Dict = {2:4, 6:9, 9:3}

Output will be [1,4,1,1,1,9,1,1,3,1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where exactly are you stuck with this problem? Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822, and then try to think about the problem logically. What steps need to be taken in order to get the answer? What parts don't you know how to do? For those parts, [can you find](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) an answer with a search engine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the values of only part (slice) of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487677/how-to-change-the-values-of-only-part-slice-of-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
for key, value in Dict.items():
    Vector[key-1] = value
```

Note I'm subtracting one because your dictionary seems to count starting at 1, but python starts counting at 0.

Answer (score -1):

```py
Vector = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Dict = {2: 4, 6: 9, 9: 3}

for k, v in Dict.items():
    Vector[k - 1] = v

print(Vector)
# output: [1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for k in d:
    if k > 0 and k <= len(v):
        v[k - 1] = d[k]
```

you can try loop for in dictionary like above. Hope it helpful for you
Addtionally your output is not correct

```
Output will be [1,4,1,1,1,9,1,1,4,1]
it should be   [1,4,1,1,1,9,1,1,3,1]
```